# How to change the endnote title from "Notes" to "Endnote"?

Tags: naming, endnotes

instead of using the title "Notes" in the endnote section, I'd like to use "Endnote". Do you know how to change the title? 
I'm using the following package: `\usepackage{endnotes}`

Comment: `\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes}` ..?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

This is described on page 1 in the [endnotes manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/endnotes/endnotes.pdf):

> **JK – Modification by Jörg Knappen 25. 2. 1991:**
>
> Introduced \notesname in the spirit of international LATEX. \notesname is set
> per default to be {Notes}, but can easily be redifined, e. g. for german language
> \renewcommand{\notesname}{Anmerkungen}

In other words, put this command in the preamble of your document (I suggest directly after where you load the endnotes-package):

```
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes}
```

If you are using [babel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel), you may change the default for each language your are using, by adding the definition of `\notesname` to the language config-file. The following is a definition for UKenglish and Norwegian:

```
%% UKenglish.cfg
%% Local config file UKenglish.cfg used by babel

%% to add an entry to British English
\addto{\captionsUKenglish}{%
    \def\notesname{Endnotes}%
}
```

New file

```
%% norsk.cfg
%% Local config file norsk.cfg used by babel

%% to add an entry to Norwegian
\addto{\captionsnorsk}{%
    \def\notesname{Sluttnoter}%
}
```

Add the cfg-files to your LaTeX-search path (if they not already are there) and update the file database.